# How to share terraform resources between modules?

Tags: terraform

I realised that terraform modules are recreating its resources per module declaration. So the way to reference a resource created in a module can only be done from the module, if it's defined as output. I'm looking for a way where I can reuse a module not in the way so it's recreating resources.

Imagine a scenario where I have three terraform modules.

One is creating an IAM policy (AWS), second is creating an IAM role, third is creating a different IAM role, and both roles share the same IAM policy.

In code:

```
# policy
resource "aws_iam_policy" "secrets_manager_read_policy" {
  name        = "SecretsManagerRead"
  description = "Read only access to secrets manager"

  policy = {} # just to shorten demonstration
}

output "policy" {
  value = aws_iam_policy.secrets_manager_read_policy
}
```

```
# test-role-1
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role_1" {
  name = "test-role-1"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

module "policy" {
  source = "../test-policy"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_secrets_manager_read_to_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.test_role_1.name
  policy_arn = module.policy.policy.arn
}
```

```
# test-role-2
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role_2" {
  name = "test-role-2"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

module "policy" {
  source = "../test-policy"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_secrets_manager_read_to_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.test_role_2.name
  policy_arn = module.policy.policy.arn
}
```

```
# create-roles
module "role-1" {
  source = "../../../modules/resources/test-role-1"
}

module "role-2" {
  source = "../../../modules/resources/test-role-2"
}
```

In this scenario terraform is trying to create two policies for each user, but I want them to use the same resource.

Is there a way to keep the code clean, so not all resources are in the same file so that a resource is identified, and the same resource can be used in multiple modules? Or it's a tree like structure where sibling modules cannot share the same child? Yes, I could define the policy first, and pass down the properties needed to child modules where I create the users, but what if I want to have a many to many relationship between them so multiple roles share the same multiple policies?

Comment: A simple way of doing it would be by separating the policy from the `iam-role` child modules.  using an attribute in  resource `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` for policy like `policy_arn = var.policy_arn` and then on the root module passing this attribute from the same policy module which is common for both iam-role modules. Additionally, the query is not 100% clear is there any error or more code to refer to?

Comment: There are usually two ways, creating outputs and then using the remote state data source or defining an output only and passing it between the modules.

Comment: @MarkoE what do you mean by “defining an output only, and passing it between the modules”?

Comment: For example, if there are policies that would apply to multiple IAM roles, then you would defined an output in one module and reuse it in one (or more) other modules as input values to attach to an IAM role. But maybe I have misunderstood your question in the first place.

Comment: So you mean reverse the flow of the "tree", where the policies are on root level, and passing down their outputs to users (which are also on root level)?

Also WRT your remote state data source solution, wouldn't that require manual ordering of resources created (a module's dependencies must be created first)?  Wouldn't that defeat the useful feature of terraform where it automatically creates the order based on resources dependencies?

Comment: @GergőHorváth You are correct. You do not want to use a data source to look up the policy if you are creating the policy in Terraform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few ways to do this:

Option 1: Move the use of the policy module up to the parent level, and have your parent (root) Terraform code look like this:

```
# create-policy
module "my-policy" {
  source = "../../../modules/resources/policy"
}

# create-roles
module "role-1" {
  source = "../../../modules/resources/test-role-1"
  policy = module.my-policy.policy
}

module "role-2" {
  source = "../../../modules/resources/test-role-2"
  policy = module.my-policy.policy
}
```

---

Option 2: Output the policy from the role modules, and also make it an optional input variable of the modules:

```
variable "policy" {
  default = null  # Make the variable optional
}

module "policy" {
  # Create the policy, only if one wasn't passed in
  count = var.policy == null ? 1 : 0
  source = "../test-policy"
}

locals {
  # Create a variable with the value of either the passed-in policy, 
  # or the one we are creating
  my-policy = var.policy == null ? module.policy[0].policy : var.policy
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_secrets_manager_read_to_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.test_role_2.name
  policy_arn = local.my-policy
}

output "policy" {
  value = locals.my-policy
}
```

Then your root code could look like this:

```
module "role-1" {
  source = "../../../modules/resources/test-role-1"
}

module "role-2" {
  source = "../../../modules/resources/test-role-2"
  policy = module.role-1.policy
}
```

The first module wouldn't get an input, so it would create a new policy. The second module would get an input, so it would use it instead of re-creating the  policy.

---

I also highly recommend looking at the source code for some of the [official AWS Terraform modules](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest), like [this one](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc). Reading the source code for those really helped me understand how to create reusable Terraform modules.

Comment: I'm definitely not getting terraform. For now what I see is the safest option is to have everything in a huge file. That way I don't have to be afraid about the order of resources created, because terraform will automatically know the dependency graph between them. I can also reuse a security group, or IAM policy, and don't have to create duplicates, or pass up/down resources as inputs/outputs to reuse them. My thinking must be wrong as I cannot find anyone else complaining about the problem of reusing resources.

Comment: Terraform builds a dependency graph of all the resources in all files and all modules. You do **NOT**  need to worry about the dependency graph breaking just because you split things into multiple files and modules!

Comment: The problem of passing up/down resources as inputs/outputs is just a small pain-point in using Terraform. You will do those a lot with Terraform, it is just how it is designed to be used.

Comment: The first option here is in the spirit of [Module Composition](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/composition) and so that guide might be useful background info for the pros and cons of that approach and how it can generalize to other problems.